# Bulk change custom options

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

[image: Change field]

I currently have close to 3000 products and all use this custom option. 
I need to change the highlighted field showing 2.99 to 3.99. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quickest approach is doing this directly in database. Do a backup and run:

```
 UPDATE `catalog_product_option_type_title` a JOIN `catalog_product_option_type_price` b ON a.option_type_id = b.option_type_id SET b.price = 3.99 WHERE a.title = 'Soft Style Unisex T-shirt'
```

Alternatively using code:

```
<?php
require_once './app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();
$resource        = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$optionTitle = 'Soft Style Unisex T-shirt';
$newPrice = 3.99;
$titleTable = $resource->getTableName('catalog/product_option_type_title');
$priceTable = $resource->getTableName('catalog/product_option_type_price');

$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

$query = " UPDATE {$titleTable} a JOIN {$priceTable} b ON a.option_type_id = b.option_type_id SET b.price = {$newPrice} WHERE a.title = '{$optionTitle}'";
$writeConnection->query($query);
```

Comment: Where would I run the alternative code?

Comment: Basically anywhere in magento. Custom controller action for example.

Comment: Completely new to running this. Any chance you can give me a quick walkthrough of what file to put this in?

Comment: Create new file change.php in application root(where index.php is) and put content of my answer there (the original answer is updated). Then run http://yoursite/change.php in your browser

Comment: Beautiful! If I wanted to change another row, do I just replace the titles?

Comment: Sure. Just change the title and the price if you need to and run it again. Be sure to remove the file from live site once you are done.